# Contained User within a Non-Contained Azure SQL Database

Tags: sql-server, azure-sql-database, contained-database

While granting access to Azure SQL databases I have been creating Contained Users directly in the SQL database like so:-

```
CREATE USER [email@domain.com] FROM EXTERNAL PROVIDER;
```

As this has been working fine, and users need to add the database name to the connection, I thought azure would know this is now a contained database.

However, upon checking, I've found the database is not contained

```
select containment, containment_desc from sys.databases
```

containment /   containment_desc
0           /   NONE
0           /   NONE

Should I now convert the database to be contained?
Are there any implications for leaving the database in this state?
Should I revert back to creating the user at both the server and DB level?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Azure SQL Database allows database-level authentication regardless of whether the database is contained or not. There is no need to change the database containment for the purpose of database-level authentication alone.

The reason you might use a contained database is to ensure better portability. See the [Contained Databases documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/databases/contained-databases) for more info.

Comment: thanks for your help. I've found the following 2 articles which help describe my question. Contained Database users, which are separate to contained databases.:-
[link1](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/security/contained-database-users-making-your-database-portable?view=sql-server-2017#contained-database-user-model)
[link2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-aad-authentication-configure#create-contained-database-users-in-your-database-mapped-to-azure-ad-identities)